# How to link static library with cmake in 64bit linux?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I build my project with cmake in linux.

I link some static libraries by using

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

target_link_libraries(MyProject /usr/lib/libImlib2.a)
```

It work perfectly in 32bit linux(In my case, Ubuntu), not in 64bit Ubuntu

This error message appears.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libImlib2.a(api.o) : relocation R_X86_64_32 againts '.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/libImlib2.a : could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2:ld returned 1 exit status
```

Some document what I found says it's problem about 64bit linux, need to set flags.

So I add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-fPIC")
```

but nothing is changed.

Could you give me some advice about what I should do?

Thank you very much for reading this question.

Comment: Try building Imlib2 yourself, it might be a packaging or upstream fault.

Comment: I do it and link my own Imlib2.a but that problem still exists.

Comment: I guess you have to rebuild `Imlib2.a` with `-fPIC` as a [common x64 issue](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/index.xml?part=1&chap=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build `Imlib2` (~all shared libraries, in fact) yourself with `-fPIC` on. Take a look at [this article](http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/amd64-pic.html) for an explanation of why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The fix that issue you need to recompile with `-fPIC` for x86_64 architecture.
More information about that is available at:

http://www.technovelty.org/c/position-independent-code-and-x86-64-libraries.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Add following lines into your main CMakeLists.txt

`IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "x86_64")
      ADD_DEFINITIONS(-fPIC)
ENDIF()`